# How to get possible keyword combination in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to fetch possible search keyword combination from particular index/document using specific keyword like I having cloth store data in elastic search and I want to fetch what possible search keyword combination can be make of specific keyword like I have data of store like
Title:

1. Black shirt for men's 100% cotton
2. blue Shirt for women
3. casual shirt for men

and I want to get possible combination of string "shirt", so result should be

1. Black Shirt
2. Shirt for men's
3. women shirt etc..
   based on data in index/document.
   Please help me out in this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are looking for, how to index and search the documents containing your sample data. please see complete example for achieving that.

**Index sample docs with default mapping**

```
{
    "title" : "women shirt"
}

{
    "title" : "Black Shirt"
}
{
    "title" : "Shirt for men's"
}
```

**Search query**

```
{
    "query" :{
        "match" :{
            "title": "shirt"
        }
    }
}
```

**And search results**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "cloth",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.14181954,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "Black Shirt"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "cloth",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 0.14181954,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "women shirt"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "cloth",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.11955717,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "Shirt for men's"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Hi Opster Elasticsearch Ninja
Thanks for your reply I really apricate you efforts. I have updated my question can you please check it again and give me you suggestion on it

Comment: @YogeshBhatt sorry i didn't get the logic of your output, can you explain more ?

Comment: Actually I want to have system like "google keyword planner", which takes our data and show possible keyword combination of given keyword that any user can enter to fetch data. hope this will help